# Can we use vector as an argument while defining our own function?

Tags: r

```
GCDF<-function(s,p)  {
  
  a<-numeric(s)

  for ( i in 0:s) {
    
    a[i]<-((p*(1-p)^i))
    b<-sum(a)
  }
  c<-p
  sum<-sum(b,c)
  print(sum)
  }
```

I have written this code to calculate cumulative probabilities from geometric distribution , this code is working fine if I calculate probabilities individually , i,e `GCDF(2,0.1)` gives me 0.271 which is same when i use `pgeom(2,0.1)` . but when I define `x<-rgeom(10,0.1)` and try to find probabilities `GCDF(x,0.1)` it shows error .  I am not able to figure it. can someone provide me solution .
thank you!